# How to log rest controller exceptions by using Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, rest, aop, spring-aop

I have a rest controller and Spring AOP class which catches service level custom exceptions and logs them but I also need to log the exceptions from controller side.

Here's my Spring AOP class;

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionLoggerAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.b.m.service.GaService.*(..)) ", throwing = "ex")
    public void logError(JoinPoint joinPoint, GaException ex) {
        Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
        String methodName = signature.getName();
        String stuff = signature.toString();
        String arguments = Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs());
        LOGGER.error("Exception have been caught in method:\n "
                + "[" + methodName + "] with arguments "
                + arguments + " and the full toString: [" + stuff + "] \n the exception is: ["
                + ex.type.getMessage() + " - " + ex.type.getAdditionalInfo() + "]");
    }
}
```

How can I add my controller class here to log the exceptions?
I added my controller package path with "**execution**" pointcut but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention **how** you added your controller package to the pointcut. I just tried to read your mind, but somehow it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Spring 3.2, you could use `@ControllerAdvice` which allows us to consolidate our multiple, scattered `@ExceptionHandlers` from before into a single, global error handling component. This would also allow us to have full control over the body of the response as well as the status code.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleGenericExceptions(Exception exception, WebRequest webRequest) {
        log.error("Handling: ", exception);

        HttpStatus errorCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

        return this.handleExceptionInternal(exception, "Unexpected Internal Server Error", new HttpHeaders(), errorCode, webRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @ControllerAdivce

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception occurred", ex);
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponse.builder().code(Error.UNKNOWN_ERROR.getCode())
                .message(Error.UNKNOWN_ERROR.getMessage()).build();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, Error.UNKNOWN_ERROR.getHttpStatus());
    }
}
```

Use a Error Response Bean to send the rest response.

```
public class ErrorResponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2405172041950251807L;
    private Integer code;
    private String message;
}
```